# How to use inner join and left join for two tables in same query using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server

Given two tables:

1. `tblBase` - database table (`code_no, empid`)
2. `@type_temp` is a temporary user defined table which will come from vb.net frontend (`code_no, name`)

Firstly I need to get `code_no` which are in `@type_temp` and not in `tblBase`.

Query:

```
select 
    t.code_no, 'Non-existing' as Remark 
from 
    @type_temp t 
left join 
    tblBase b on t.code_no = b.code_no 
where 
    b.code_no is null
```

Next I need to get all `code_no` that have `empid = 1`.

Query :

```
select 
    t.code_no, 'Existing' as Remark 
from 
    @type_temp t 
inner join 
    tblBase b on t.code_no = b.code_no 
where 
    b.empid = 1
```

I need to use both these queries together.

Currently I'm using `union` to club the two.

```
select 
    t.code_no, 'Non-existing' as Remark 
from 
    @type_temp t 
left join 
    tblBase b on t.code_no = b.code_no 
where 
    b.code_no is null

union

select 
    t.code_no, 'Existing' as Remark 
from 
    @type_temp t 
inner join 
    tblBase b on t.code_no = b.code_no 
where 
    b.empid = 1
```

I do not want union here. Any other alternative possible?

Comment: ***WHY*** not the `UNION` ?? That's the easiest and best way I can think of ....

Comment: @marc_s Is it efficient to use union in terms of performance?

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```sql
SELECT type_temp.code_no
     , CASE WHEN tblBase.code_no IS NULL THEN 'Non-existing' ELSE 'Existing' END AS Remark
FROM   @type_temp AS type_temp
 LEFT
  JOIN tblBase
    ON tblBase.code_no = type_temp.code_no
WHERE  tblBase.empid = 1
OR     tblBase.code_no IS NULL
;
```

Answer (score 0):

An even better option than [@gvee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69973049/14868997), is to put the conditions into the `ON` clause

```
SELECT
  type_temp.code_no,
  CASE WHEN tblBase.code_no IS NULL THEN 'Non-existing' ELSE 'Existing' END AS Remark
FROM @type_temp AS type_temp
LEFT JOIN tblBase ON tblBase.code_no = type_temp.code_no
    AND tblBase.empid = 1;
```

This is likely to be more performant, as the join is pre-filtered.